# WebApi HelpPage HttpResponseMessage SetActualResponseType

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using the WebApi Help pages within an MVC4 project.

As per the following link, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/10/13/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-2-providing-custom-samples-on-the-help-page.aspx I have been setting the HelpPageConfig to set actual response types.

I have a controller that has two get methods on it

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the list of plans for a specified portfolio
/// </summary>
/// <param name="portfolioIdentifier">Portfolio Identifier (guid)</param>
/// <returns>
/// Returns a list of <see cref="RestDTOs.Plan"/> Plan objects
/// </returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid portfolioIdentifier)
    {
    }

/// <summary>
/// Get full plan details.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="planIdentifier">Plan Identifier (guid)</param>
/// <returns>
/// Returns the <see cref="RestDTOs.Plan"/> Plan object
/// </returns>
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Detail(Guid planIdentifier)
    {
    }
```

Within HelpPageConfig.cs i have added the following to try and set an example ResponseBody format

```
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(Plan), "Plan", "GET");
```

This is working great on the Get method, but is not producing anything on the Detail method

What do I need to add to the HelpPageConfig so that the web api help will pick up and produce samples for the Detail method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(Plan), "Plan", "Detail");`...the second parameter here is expecting an action name...I see you are using Web API 1, so just FYI...in Web API 2, there is an attribute called ResponseType which you can use to decorate on an action to describe the actual response type for a given action..

Comment: Thanks for that. I misunderstood the actionName parameter. I though you only specified the http verb, and not the actual method name

Comment: MVC5 has a built in attribute to set the response type, please check answer below.

Answer (score 5):

MVC 5 has a built in attribute to set the response type.

More information here:
http://thesoftwaredudeblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/webapi-2-helppage-using-responsetype-attribute-instead-of-setactualresponsetype/

Just use:

```
    ResponseType(typeof([Your_Class]))]
```